# Compile .Rnw file with command

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I have .Rnw file which generates me a report. In RStudio you compile it with button 'Compile PDF'.

But is there a way to compile this file with command in script and pass one character variable?

I tried to use function knit() but it only produces .tex file and I would like to obtain also pdf.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `knit2pdf` in the `knitr` package does the trick ;)