# What are the commands executed if I press the "Compile PDF" button on a "Rnw" file in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, sweave

Once again I am in the situation that I want to replicate what is happening when I press the <kbd>Compile PDF</kbd> button on an .Rnw file in RStudio with my own R script.

For example I create a new `.Rnw` file in RStudio with File > New File > R Sweave. It looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<echo=F, results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
xtable(mtcars)
@

\end{document}
```

I inserted a chunk with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and used the autocompletion to set the chunk options. Hence I assume I did everything with the default settings as RStudio assumes it to be. When I press <kbd>Compile PDF</kbd> everything works without problems. But when I execute:

```
knitr::knit2pdf("Sweave-test.Rnw")
```

I get an Error "It seems you are using the Sweave-specific syntax". Hence there are additional steps needed.

What I came up with so far is the following:

```
library(knitr)
tempfile1 <- tempfile(fileext=".Rnw")
Sweave2knitr(file = "input.Rnw", output = tempfile1)
tempfile2 <- tempfile(fileext=".tex")
knit(tempfile1, output=tempfile2)
tools::texi2pdf(tempfile2, clean=T)
system(paste("open", sub(".tex", ".pdf", basename(tempfile2))))
```

(The last line is OSX specific I think).

But **I am curious to know what RStudio is doing exactly**. I looked into the [RStudio github page](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio) but am not sure where to find the command. Other Stackoverlow questions show that there are slight [differences between what the button does and `knit2pdf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555002/difference-between-compile-pdf-and-knit2pdf). It seems the question has been [asked over and over again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555002/difference-between-compile-pdf-and-knit2pdf), also in relation to the <kbd>Knit Html</kbd> button. It might use functions from the `knitr` package, the `markdown`, the `rmarkdown` package, `texi2pdf` from the `tools` package, `Sweave` from the `utils` package or `pandoc`. I have no Idea...

Related question (that all got some rather vague answers):

- [Difference: "Compile PDF" button in RStudio vs. knit() and knit2pdf()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591487/difference-compile-pdf-button-in-rstudio-vs-knit-and-knit2pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Difference between "Compile PDF" and knit2pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555002/difference-between-compile-pdf-and-knit2pdf)
- [How to convert R Markdown to HTML? I.e., What does "Knit HTML" do in Rstudio 0.96?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646665/how-to-convert-r-markdown-to-html-i-e-what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-9)
- [What does “Knit HTML” do in Rstudio 0.98?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881289/what-does-knit-html-do-in-rstudio-0-98)
- [Compile .Rnw file with command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115713/compile-rnw-file-with-command)
- [How to build Knitr document from the command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132704/how-to-build-knitr-document-from-the-command-line)

Currently I am using RStudio 1.0.136.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is just Sweave to turn a Rnw file into tex file and then calling pdflatex.exe to turn it from a tex file into a pdf file.

```
Sweave("Sweave-test.Rnw")
system("pdflatex.exe Sweave-test.tex")
```

And if you encountered a File Sweave.sty not found, you will need to add a path this file in your MiKTeX Options, please see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153193/latex-error-sweave-sty-not-found/153194#153194).